# Install SQL Server Silently Using C# Forms Application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an windows application developed in C#, I need to install it on a PC which will just have the Operating System and .Net Framework installed. Now I have to give an option to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition on that PC, using this windows application. I have coded for installing/uninstalling a windows service, but struck with sql server installation. could someone help me out in doing this.

Comment: Is sqlCE not an option?

Comment: silent Sql server install?  errr..   If user.pulse == 0 msiexec....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the guidelines in [How to Embed SQL Server Express in an Application](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/940.how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application.aspx). It covers *everything* you need, including pickiing up the right distribution, choosing an appropriate installation method (wpi vs. setup.exe) and how to configure the installation. the wiki even has a C# code on how to detect a previous Express instalation, how to invoke the WPI (Web Platform Installer) for SQL Express from C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
  @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\webplatforminstaller.exe",
  " /id SQLExpress");
```

or using the "wpi://" URL handler:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("wpi://SQLExpress/");
```

or using the Web App Galery:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
  "http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=&appid=SQLExpress");
```

and, finally, using the SQL Express setup (recommended for advanced configuration):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process processObj = 
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\temp\sqlsetup\setup.exe",

@"/q /Action=Install /Hideconsole /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=True 
 /Features=SQL,Tools /InstanceName=SQLExpress
 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""Builtin\Administrators"" 
 /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""DomainName\UserName"" /SQLSVCPASSWORD=""StrongPassword""");
```

and it has the full list of setup parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [msiexec.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can simply install an MSI by passing the MSI path. Using command you can set whether to show UI during the installation or make it a silent installation,

`string installCommandString = "/i {0} /qn";`

- **/qn**: Set user interface level: None
- **/qb**: Set user interface level: Basic UI
- **/qr**: Set user interface level: Reduced UI
- **/qf**: Set user interface level: Full UI (default)

`C# code`

```
string installCommandString = "/i {0} /qn";

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;

startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(installCommandString, "SQL Server MSI Path");

process.Start();
```

Comment: Does it work with .exe files? I can't find the .msi for sql express installer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard MSI installer, built into Visual Studio then there is an option to set pre-requisites.

- Right click the MSI
- Select properties
- Select prerequisites

Near the bottom there is an option for SQL Server Express and you can specify where to get the components from - vendor, or from a location on your servers.

Comment: I don't want this as an prerequisite, I need it to have as a feature to install SQL Server. Say Like I have c# windows form, I will give an button click option to user to install sql server. I want this to be done completely using C# code.