# How to deliver Windows Forms desktop application to client

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2012, desktop-application

I have built a Windows Forms application using C# and SQL Server 2012 to save and retrieve data from the database. It is my first project and experience kindly guide me in detail.

How can I deliver my desktop application with the database to the client's site - which steps are required? Please guide me in detail and thanks in advance.

How to launch the application?

Do I need to install full SQL Server 2012 on the client computer?

And all steps which are required?

Comment: you have to install MS SQL Server to client's machine if you are using it on your project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520362/install-sql-server-silently-using-c-sharp-forms-application

Comment: Is there some reason you are using SQL 2012 instead of the current version (SQL 2017 as of this writing, with SQL 2019 expected soon)? Consider the free SQL Express edition, especially SqlLocalDB if you only need local access from your WinForm app and can run within the [supported features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017) (e.g. db size less than 10GB).

Comment: It means i need to fully instal sql server at client computer? How can i launch my winform application?